# Simple python nested loops - index out of range

Tags: python, list, for-loop, set

When I run the following code, I get an error:

```
def genSet(nums):
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
        for x in range(0, len(nums)-1):
            if nums[x] == nums[i]:
                del nums[x] 
    return nums

a = [5, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3]  
print genSet(a)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "49.py", line 9, in <module>
    print genSet(a)
  File "49.py", line 4, in genSet
    if nums[x] == nums[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As far as I can tell (I replaced the if statement with "print x, i") the two for loops are fine, so why is the index out of range?

Comment: you cannot `del` from a list while looping over it.

Comment: @thg435: Well, you can, but unexpected things may happen if you do.

Comment: @Tim: "Well, son, you can play with matches, but unexpected things may happen" ))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't do `del nums[x]`, since this way you make `nums` shorter and thus get an exception.

you can simply make a set out of the list by `set_nums = set(nums)`

Answer (score 3):

You are removing elements from `nums`, therefore it becomes shorter and an IndexError occures.

Anyway, your code would remove everything, because every element has as least one identical element in the list (itself!). If you want to create a "unique" list of elements, create a set:

```
unique_set = set(nums)
```

and convert it to list again:

```
unique_list = list(set(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the indices where the number is the same, make your list to a numpy array `nums = np.array(nums)` and use the [`np.delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

The example you give can be simply replaced by a one-line code:

```
print set([5, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3])
```

If I really want filter out the duplicates in a list myself, I would:

```
nums = sorted([5, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3])
print reduce(lambda x,y:(y not in x and x+[y]) or x, nums, [])
```